# Changing the colour of a cell and positioning text vertically in that cell

Tags: tables, color

How can I change the vertically position of the text 'Data' in the multicolumn cell?
And how can I colour only that sell?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}||m{2cm}|m{2cm}|@{}m{0cm}@{}}
\hhline{|-||--|}
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering \large Table} & Day 1 & Day 2 & \\[2.5pt]
\hhline{|~||--|}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Data} & \\
\hhline{:=:|--|}
Subject 1 & 13.4 & 14.6 & \\
\hhline{|-||-|-|}
Subject 2 & 11.9 & 14.3 & \\
\hhline{|-||-|-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing the vertical position of that cell? Do you want to increase the height of that cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `makecell`, which defines a `\Gape` commandn, to add vertical padding at the top and/or bottom of individual cells. Note the `table` option of `scolor` spares you loading `colortbl`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}||m{2cm}|m{2cm}|@{}m{0cm}@{}}
  \hhline{|-||--|}
  \multirowcell{2}[-1ex]{\large Table} & Day 1 & Day 2 &   \\
  \hhline{|~||--|}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\Gape[6pt][0pt]{\cellcolor{Lavender}Data}}  & \\
  \hhline{:=:|>{\doublerulesepcolor{Lavender}\arrayrulecolor{Lavender}}==>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}\noalign{\vspace{-0.4pt}}
  \cline{2-3}
  Subject 1                            & 13.4  & 14.6  &   \\
  \hhline{|-||-|-|}
  Subject 2                            & 11.9  & 14.3  &   \\
  \hhline{|-||-|-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]